# Js file for find location / Address?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins, cordova

I need address in project. I am getting address by using Latitude and longitude with including below scripting code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
```

Is there any respective .js file is there to find location instead of loading above URL ?

Please give some suggestions because with out internet connection my app is not loading, It is throwing Application Error.

Comment: Geolocation APIs use a database to find out location by IP address. You either have to have the data locally or need to connect to a remote service.

Comment: So you're asking how to find a street address without an internet connection? How could that possibly work?

Comment: Do you expect to include every street address in the world inside your Javascript code?

Comment: Yeah it is not possible.. But how can start my app quickly. iF internet is not there it will take nearly 1 minute to start app. How to reduce the loading time ?

Comment: Sorry for silly question but I have problem with loading time  with out internet.

Comment: Load the script asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. How can we load the script asynchronously ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click [here](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/javascript/) for your query. I think it will be usefull for you.

Answer (score 0):

why  dont you use a function() to get the location and dispaly it within the div??
chk out below:

```
function Location() {

            var latlng = userLatValue + ',' + userLngValue;


            var locationUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="
                    + latlng + "&sensor=false";

            var locationRequest = $.ajax({
                type : 'GET',
                url : locationUrl,
                async : false,
                data : "json"

            });


            locationRequest.done(function(data) {
                if(data.results.length > 0) {
                     userLocationName = data.results[0].formatted_address;
                    //alert('address: ' + userLocationName);
                }                           
            });

            locationRequest.fail(function(jqXHR, textstatus, error) {
                //alert("error:");});

    }
```